# JQuery addClass crashes in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, crash, anchor, addclass

I have several anchor <a> tags in a <span> on my page. They have an id of "m" appended to a sequential number. So, for example, there might be

```
<a id="m1" href="..." > 
<a id="m2" href="...">
```

etc. up to possibly

```
<a id="m1000"...>
```

etc.

In my javascript code, I am performing the following:

```
var idNumber = 5;
var selector = "m" + String(idNumber); 
$('#' + selector).addClass("myNewClass"); 
    //  myNewClass is defined in the stylesheet.
```

This works fine for all browsers like **Chrome, Firefox** and **Safari**, but the last line (the one with the addClass) causes **IE11** (*not sure about other versions*) to crash, and it comes up with a dialog saying "...Searching for a solution to the problem..." and eventually forces me to close the IE window. I can even try hardcoding it like

```
$('#m4').addClass("myNewClass"); and IE still crashes.
```

What could be causing this behaviour? **Could it be the version of jquery that I am using? (1.5.1)?** But it is very strange in my opinion. When I use Firebug or Chrome Inspect element, I get no problems. When I use the IE page inspector, I get no errors visible, but the page crashes.

I would greatly appreciate any help!

Thanks in advance,
Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for completeness sake, I have found the solution to the problem. If I add a class to the anchor tags then IE too works as expected. So, instead of having <a id="m1"...> I now have <a id="m1" class="myInitialClass"> This apparently prevents the addClass from crashing on IE!

Answer (score 0):

I think here:

```
var selector = "m" + String(idNumber);
```

You don't need to convert an integer to string because if you concatenate an integer with string that automaically parsed as string and instead of performing **add** operation to it, just concatenate the two elements together.

So you can try this code:

```
var idNumber = 5;
var selector = "m" + idNumber; 
$('#' + selector).addClass("myNewClass"); 
//  myNewClass is defined in the stylesheet.
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I do not think this is the problem, the reason being is that even if I hardcode it as follows: $('#m4').addClass("myNewClass") or $('#m55').addClass("myNewClass") IE still crashes.

Comment: If there are loops in js code are available then that could cause this kind of issues.